Need help on freeze and unfreeze a kubernetes pod
I want to freeze and unfreeze a specific kubernetes pod.
Below are the steps which I've tried:

With the help of kubectl exec -it command entered into the pod.
Verified the processes in that pod. One process is running with pid 1.
Tried kill -19 1 to freeeze and kill -18 1 for  After executing it not observed any impact.

I saw in one of the article pid 1 is special pid which ignores signals.
Please try to help how to achieve this.

Does it work if you do it from outside the pod instead of from inside it?
